# Reading content from a text file saved to a byte field in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm missing something in between. I store the CSV file content in databas, not in a file. The 2nd line below is wrong, I want to read the byte data and assign it to array of lines. So I can loop the results as if I had read directly from a file on disk. Many thanks...

```
FileContentResult x23File = File(x23.FileData, 
                                "application/text", x23.Filename);

string[] Lines = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x23File);
```

Comment: x23.FileData is my already saved CSV file content from the SQL Server database. I need to do something with x23File since its not building. I get Error 9 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult' to 'byte[]'

Comment: `FileContentResult` is an MVC concept; if your intent is to read the contents, I fail to see how that is relevant. What is the type of `x23` here? is `x23.FileData` a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because `x23File` is not a `byte[]`. Your second line should actually be

`string[] Lines = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x23File.FileContents).Split(new String[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: Almost there, I get: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]' . Maybe storing it as a byte has lost all the carriage returns from the original file or something

Comment: @John no, that is unrelated; that is a compile-time message that tells you that your code isn't sensible in the first place; it says nothing about the contents at runtime

Comment: @John You need to split on newline as your current code returns the whole file as 1 string. I edited my response so that you should get an array.

Comment: Assuming CRLF is perhaps not wise; also, it is unnecessary and inefficient to construct a single `string` with the entire file contents

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that `x23.FileData` is a `byte[]`, you probably want:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(x23.FileData))
using(var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        lines.Add(line);
}
```

Now `lines` has all the separate lines. Note you could also consume this data in a non-buffered way via `IEnumerable<string>`. For example:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(byte[] source, Encoding enc = null)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream(source))
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(ms, enc ?? Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return line;
    }
}
```